# Merge Field value not populating in Email Template

Tags: email, workflow

I have created a email template which includes few merge fields, but {!Case.Offering_Level__c} value is not populating when email alert is triggered by workflow.
When i checked test and verify preview i was able to see the value of field {!Case.Offering_Level__c}.

Comment: FLS issue between you as admin vs running user that executes the email generation transaction?

Comment: Did you check field level permissions?

Comment: Yes , i have checked FLS, each profile in my Org. has visible permission for this field.

Comment: is it possible this is an order of execution issue -- the WFR that sends the email executes before a Process Builder or Flow sets the value of Case.Offering_Level__c?

Comment: Hi Priyank, did you ever figure this out?  I've run up against the same issue ... test and verify preview show the correct merge fields, and if I have the email sent to my email address, it comes through with the merge fields.  But when I fire it from a workflow trigger, the email comes through but the merge fields are blank.